# getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback LG nexus 4 Version 4.4.2

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am getting `getbluetoothservice() called with no bluetoothmanagercallback`.

The app is working in other device but only in nexus 4, it is not working. Why it's happen?

Can anyone give me a idea about this. I goggle this but not getting satisfied answers.